# How to keep application running on external monitor when ubuntu locked

Tags: lock-screen, external-monitor

I would like to keep a dashboard-style app running full-screen on one of my monitors while I'm away from my computer. (And the computer is locked.) I don't need any user input in the application, I'd just like at least one monitor to not switch off after a while when my computer is locked.

Has anyone done something similar? Or am I better off running a dashboard on a separate computer?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but you could  probably have a background service which would periodically output an image (jpg, png, etc) which you could then set as the lock screen wallpaper.  The service would just overwrite the image to update the screen.

Granted, it's untested and there's the chance that the lockscreen won't refresh when the image changes.  Also, it doesn't answer the question of keeping the monitors from sleeping (I'm looking for that answer as well, which is how I found your question).